# Better explanation of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

Hi I've been teaching myself C++ for a while now and have been at the arrays section. I haven't quite been understanding arrays (and nested for loops) and would very much appreciate some help

1) How does

```
const int ROWS = 5;
const int COLUMNS = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)

{
    for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; ++j)
            cout << i << "," << j << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

display

```
0,0 0,1 0,2
1,0 1,1 1,2
2,0 2,1 2,2
3,0 3,1 3,2
4,0 4,1 4,2
```

While glancing at the code, it looks to me that it should look more like

```
0,0 0,1 0,2 1,0 1,1 1,2 2,0 2,1 2,2 3,0 3,1 3,2 4,0 4,1 4,2
```

Why is it automatically creating a new line after 3 sets of 2?

2) I have no idea what iterators are. I've used them in the vector file name yet I still don't know what they are and how they change data

3) What do these '[]' do in this code?

```
const int ROWS = 3;
    const int COLUMNS = 3;
    char board[ROWS][COLUMNS] = { {'O', 'X', 'O'},
                                   {' ', 'X', 'X'},
                                     {'X', 'O', 'O'} };
    cout << "Here's the Tic-Tac-Toe board:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; ++j)
            cout << board[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
```

More specifically, what are

```
[ROWS][COLUMNS]
```

and why do they belong in those boxes. and how does

```
cout << board[i][j]
```

output the tic tac toe board.

I realize this is a but much to ask for, but I have no idea what i'm programming now in the book and would really appreciate the help

Comment: What languages did you program in before you taught yourself C++? Loops are pretty much the same in most programming languages, and arrays aren't too different either (although C and C++ arrays have some additional aspects related to pointers that can be confusing).

Comment: @Barmar C++ is my first language.

Comment: Sorry. I wish people would make a distinction between being new to programming in general and new to a particular programming language. When you said "I'm teaching myself C++", I assumed you meant that you know how to program in other languages and were just learning C++.

Comment: @Barmar Completely fine, I assume I would easily make that same mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The line "cout << endl;" is creating the newline. The line before prints two comma separated values, i (which is the iteration of the first for loop) and j, the iteration of the second for loop. The second loop is incrementing j until j = COLUMNS (3). So you are getting the 3 loops of the two values, followed by a new line. This is then repeated because of the first loop, incrementing i until it is equal to ROWS (5). Which is why you get 5 lines.

2)The iterators in this case are i and j. They are int variables that measure the position in the loop, as they are incremented each time the loop operates.

3) [] declares an array. For example

```
int myArray[3]
```

creates an array that has space for three ints.

```
char board[ROWS][COLUMNS]
```

Is creating a *multidimensional* array. So you have an array with a length of ROWS in one dimension, and an array with a length of COLUMNS in the other dimension.

Then, within your loop

```
cout << board[i][j]
```

prints out the values at position i in the first dimension of the array and position j in the second dimension.